# Leaflet - make all tile layers clickable/interactive

Tags: javascript, leaflet, vector-tiles

I have a leaflet map that has multiple vector tile layers from GeoJSON points using [Leaflet VectorGrid](http://leaflet.github.io/Leaflet.VectorGrid/vectorgrid-api-docs.html):

```
var layer1 = L.vectoGrid.slicer(geoJSON1, {interactive: true}).on('click', function(e)...)  
.addTo(map);  
var layer2 = L.vectoGrid.slicer(geoJSON2, {interactive: true}).on('click', function(e)...)  
.addTo(map);
```

Adding them to the map in this way makes only the topmost layer (i.e. `layer2`) clickable. I've found that adding a `L.control.layers` to remove the upper layers allows the first layer to be clicked (`layer1`), but then only one layer is visible.

Is there a way to make all the tile layers clickable/interactive when they are all displayed? Ideally the mouse pointer would change when hovering over a feature in any layer from the basic hand to the pointer hand to indicate that a feature is clickable.

Edit (July 20, 2017): I found this Gist: [Click through multiple layers of Leaflet VectorGrid](https://gist.github.com/perliedman/84ce01954a1a43252d1b917ec925b3dd#file-click-through-layers-js). It seems potentially helpful, but the mouse pointer doesn't change except when hovering over the topmost layer. It's also returning numerous instances of the feature clicked on.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment above, this one works:

[Click through multiple layers of Leaflet VectorGrid](https://gist.github.com/perliedman/84ce01954a1a43252d1b917ec925b3dd#file-click-through-layers-js)

Some pitfalls are there, so I added the problems I came across and workaround fixes I did. See comments I wrote in the link above.